# How to change the “Account Username” & “Account Password” text from WooCommerce checkout form?

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, checkout

I need to change the text “Account username”,Account password”, and the placeholder texts in those fields from the checkout page. Can anyone please help me regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce: Account Password Field in Checkout page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071216/woocommerce-account-password-field-in-checkout-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's really easy. Should be something like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'woocommerce_checkout_fields');

function woocommerce_checkout_fields($fields) {

    $fields['account']['account_username']['label'] = __( 'Username', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['account']['account_username']['placeholder'] = __( 'Account username', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['account']['account_password']['label'] = __( 'Password', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['account']['account_password']['placeholder'] = __( 'Account password', 'woocommerce' );

    return $fields;
}
```

Above code just exchanged the label and placeholder. You can change it to your needs.